# Übersetzung von "stand out from the rest of the class"

Tags: translation, english-to-german, preposition

> With his grades, Sascha stands out from the rest of the class.

Die empfohlenen Übersetzungen von [**stand out**](http://dictionary.reverso.net/english-german/stand%20out) sind **hervorstechen** und  **auffallen**.

> (a) Mit seinen Noten sticht Sascha vom Rest der Klasse hervor.
>
> (b) Mit seinen Noten fällt Sascha vom Rest der Klasse auf.

Klingen beide Sätze in Ordnung? Und zwar, ist die Präposition **von** die richtige Wahl?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Hervorstechen** würde ich mit der Präposition **aus** verwenden. Ich würde auch nicht schreiben, dass Sascha *aus dem Rest* hervorsticht, weil das bedeuten würde, dass Sascha selbst ein Mitglied des Restes ist. Das ist er aber ja nicht, sondern das Wort *Rest* soll gerade ausdrücken, dass Sascha nicht zu dieser Menge gehört. Also wäre mein Vorschlag:

> Mit seinen Noten sticht Sascha aus der Klasse hervor.

---

Gefühlsmäßig würde ich sagen, dass **auffallen** gänzlich ohne Vergleichsgröße benutzt wird:

> Mit seinen Noten fällt Sascha auf.

Möchte man die Klasse trotzdem nennen, könnte man *in der Klasse*, also sozusagen den Ort des Auffallens, einfügen, wobei mehrere Satzpositionen denkbar sind, z. B.:

> In der Klasse fällt Sascha mit seinen Noten auf.

Man könnte auch sagen

> Bei *der* Klasse fällt Sascha mit seinen Noten auf.

Hier wird das Wort *der* betont; der Satz enthält einen abfälligen Ton bzgl. der Klasse. (Im Sinne von *So schlecht, wie diese Klasse ist, fällt Sascha ja direkt mit seinen guten Noten auf.*)

---

Ein alternativer Vorschlag meinerseits wäre das Verb **sich abheben**:

> Mit seinen Noten hebt sich Sascha vom Rest der Klasse ab.

Hier ist *von/vom* die richtige Wahl der Präposition.

Comment: Ich glaube "auffallen" ohne Adverb ist ein bisschen zu neutral. "Stand out" kann wohl auch durch schlechte Noten sein, aber impliziert werden gute. "Auffallen" ist da für mein Gefühl zu neutral. Dein Vorschlag "sich abheben" ist viel besser. Ich habe allerdings die ganze Zeit das Gefühl es müsste "durch seine Noten" sein